# passing from specific class to props function sccs and vuejs

Tags: vue.js, sass, scss-mixins

I want to pass a class according to a props without having to duplicate the scss code
indeed if I duplicate the code by putting the class it works but I would only like to modify certain value by adding the appropriate class

components

````
     ``` :class="[
        theme === 'darkModeTheme'
          ? 'darkModeTheme'
          : theme === 'toggleLanguage'
          ? 'toggleLanguage'
          : ''
      ]"
// props
theme: { type: String }
```
````

here is an example of the scss

````
```

        &:checked {
            background: color(menu);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 80px 40px;
            .darkModeTheme { //class to be taken into account if defined on the component to call
                background: url("../../../assets/img/sky-stars.jpg");
            }
            &::before {
                .toggleLanguage {
                    background-image: url("~@/assets/img/en.png");
                }

                // background-image: url("~@/assets/img/en.png");
                left: 40px;
            }
        }

        &:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            left: 0;
            background-size: 30px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            @include easeOut;
            cursor: pointer;
            // background-image: url("~@/assets/img/fr.svg");

            .darkModeTheme { //class to be taken into account if defined on the component to call
                background-image: color(toggleTheme);
            }
            .toggleLanguage { //class to be taken into account if defined on the component to call
                background-image: url("~@/assets/img/fr.svg");
            }
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your template, the dynamic class should be defined like

```
:class="{
         'darkModeTheme':  theme === 'darkModeTheme',
          'toggleLanguage': theme === 'toggleLanguage'
      }"
```

Comment: thanks i modified but it doesn't take the values i must have another